# Table outside page

Tags: tables, landscape

I have a large table in landscape mode in my Appendix. I just added the section title and the table now is "floating" outside of the page margin. I can't tell where this can be changed in my code that looks like following

```
\documentclass[a4paper, leqno, oneside] {report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{hvfloat}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\section*{A.1 Death rate Male}
\hvFloat[nonFloat=true,capWidth=w,capPos=t,rotAngle=90,objectPos=c]{table}{%
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} 
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{26}{r} }
\AA r & 1989 & 1990 & 1991 & 1992 & 1993 & 1994 & 1995 & 1996 & 1997 & 1998 & 1999 & 2000 & 2001 & 2002 & 2003 & 2004 & 2005 & 2006 & 2007 & 2008 & 2009 & 2010 & 2011 & 2012 & 2013 & 2014 \\
\midrule
64 & 711 & 765 & 719 & 698 & 608 & 619 & 595 & 609 & 522 & 582 & 531 & 560 & 539 & 531 & 533 & 579 & 514 & 576 & 665 & 707 & 670 & 731 & 637 & 606 & 590 & 518 \\
65 & 843 & 804 & 774 & 778 & 721 & 698 & 620 & 653 & 673 & 626 & 557 & 553 & 551 & 544 & 620 & 600 & 617 & 644 & 669 & 686 & 734 & 739 & 743 & 669 & 652 & 616 \\
66 & 899 & 894 & 872 & 861 & 788 & 727 & 782 & 709 & 696 & 669 & 591 & 596 & 612 & 632 & 637 & 611 & 699 & 678 & 596 & 657 & 709 & 765 & 796 & 805 & 749 & 696 \\
67 & 1032 & 927 & 989 & 891 & 898 & 774 & 783 & 822 & 726 & 757 & 707 & 633 & 627 & 626 & 628 & 652 & 636 & 629 & 690 & 627 & 660 & 767 & 797 & 793 & 807 & 824 \\
68 & 1141 & 1119 & 1023 & 1026 & 980 & 909 & 896 & 846 & 809 & 775 & 801 & 724 & 724 & 687 & 710 & 682 & 703 & 663 & 697 & 741 & 651 & 697 & 844 & 803 & 878 & 866 \\
69 & 1324 & 1182 & 1197 & 1057 & 1048 & 986 & 968 & 921 & 868 & 861 & 829 & 827 & 766 & 790 & 705 & 739 & 721 & 708 & 715 & 780 & 763 & 755 & 830 & 856 & 914 & 954 \\
70 & 1122 & 1383 & 1311 & 1289 & 1144 & 1114 & 1043 & 1000 & 958 & 923 & 902 & 893 & 825 & 823 & 810 & 744 & 762 & 786 & 758 & 766 & 749 & 829 & 781 & 866 & 911 & 976 \\
71 & 1254 & 1271 & 1398 & 1349 & 1299 & 1155 & 1155 & 1170 & 1128 & 1040 & 1056 & 932 & 928 & 879 & 960 & 884 & 775 & 814 & 773 & 798 & 808 & 838 & 835 & 761 & 927 & 983 \\
72 & 1369 & 1368 & 1274 & 1495 & 1506 & 1347 & 1183 & 1158 & 1175 & 1139 & 1104 & 1086 & 988 & 1014 & 941 & 935 & 866 & 838 & 828 & 854 & 826 & 863 & 864 & 891 & 843 & 924 \\
73 & 1434 & 1423 & 1439 & 1386 & 1563 & 1500 & 1445 & 1318 & 1277 & 1232 & 1177 & 1116 & 1043 & 1080 & 1058 & 994 & 1010 & 906 & 884 & 861 & 913 & 877 & 923 & 993 & 943 & 869 \\
74 & 1583 & 1544 & 1505 & 1485 & 1397 & 1577 & 1723 & 1467 & 1399 & 1348 & 1287 & 1235 & 1182 & 1138 & 1121 & 1033 & 1088 & 1023 & 904 & 994 & 956 & 944 & 937 & 1032 & 1033 & 1064 \\
75 & 1622 & 1706 & 1621 & 1459 & 1534 & 1453 & 1660 & 1690 & 1587 & 1439 & 1475 & 1340 & 1272 & 1265 & 1197 & 1087 & 1137 & 1081 & 1062 & 1020 & 987 & 1033 & 985 & 1026 & 1071 & 1085 \\
76 & 1714 & 1752 & 1681 & 1569 & 1597 & 1548 & 1481 & 1694 & 1773 & 1705 & 1448 & 1453 & 1415 & 1302 & 1303 & 1224 & 1218 & 1189 & 1112 & 1051 & 1095 & 1014 & 1101 & 1086 & 1119 & 1116 \\
77 & 1862 & 1858 & 1874 & 1782 & 1795 & 1677 & 1678 & 1596 & 1776 & 1796 & 1700 & 1582 & 1510 & 1527 & 1445 & 1319 & 1284 & 1258 & 1219 & 1205 & 1171 & 1174 & 1129 & 1146 & 1126 & 1182 \\
78 & 1801 & 1888 & 1860 & 1822 & 1867 & 1714 & 1709 & 1593 & 1570 & 1870 & 1871 & 1687 & 1576 & 1600 & 1497 & 1373 & 1370 & 1334 & 1365 & 1307 & 1279 & 1325 & 1227 & 1196 & 1110 & 1197 \\
79 & 1874 & 1975 & 1854 & 1914 & 1856 & 1680 & 1796 & 1706 & 1665 & 1595 & 1919 & 1906 & 1788 & 1681 & 1621 & 1504 & 1566 & 1435 & 1345 & 1335 & 1295 & 1349 & 1319 & 1246 & 1219 & 1196 \\
80 & 1786 & 1906 & 1862 & 1882 & 1994 & 1860 & 1755 & 1763 & 1791 & 1652 & 1653 & 1879 & 1934 & 1846 & 1698 & 1630 & 1643 & 1580 & 1529 & 1468 & 1495 & 1452 & 1366 & 1400 & 1320 & 1288 \\
81 & 1819 & 1983 & 1968 & 1872 & 1933 & 1837 & 1821 & 1860 & 1815 & 1775 & 1816 & 1624 & 1975 & 1944 & 1990 & 1745 & 1741 & 1698 & 1603 & 1647 & 1503 & 1484 & 1365 & 1538 & 1405 & 1350 \\
82 & 1686 & 1810 & 1898 & 1940 & 1890 & 1775 & 1919 & 1821 & 1706 & 1761 & 1803 & 1763 & 1586 & 2045 & 1987 & 1777 & 1777 & 1698 & 1700 & 1639 & 1540 & 1560 & 1512 & 1544 & 1485 & 1486 \\
83 & 1671 & 1699 & 1792 & 1841 & 1845 & 1753 & 1814 & 1873 & 1795 & 1789 & 1793 & 1757 & 1753 & 1658 & 2068 & 1922 & 1900 & 1766 & 1758 & 1724 & 1653 & 1660 & 1662 & 1587 & 1515 & 1566 \\
84 & 1560 & 1632 & 1671 & 1681 & 1791 & 1728 & 1834 & 1804 & 1783 & 1845 & 1709 & 1729 & 1697 & 1715 & 1606 & 1959 & 2003 & 1917 & 1809 & 1761 & 1707 & 1648 & 1665 & 1661 & 1659 & 1540 \\
85 & 1395 & 1449 & 1543 & 1601 & 1659 & 1594 & 1718 & 1745 & 1713 & 1794 & 1719 & 1703 & 1697 & 1719 & 1710 & 1606 & 1963 & 1942 & 1816 & 1775 & 1808 & 1715 & 1712 & 1672 & 1598 & 1647 \\
86 & 1280 & 1424 & 1333 & 1404 & 1556 & 1460 & 1665 & 1635 & 1588 & 1641 & 1709 & 1695 & 1578 & 1605 & 1656 & 1574 & 1586 & 1902 & 1919 & 1828 & 1714 & 1748 & 1697 & 1741 & 1601 & 1605 \\
87 & 1141 & 1171 & 1210 & 1266 & 1368 & 1260 & 1375 & 1494 & 1440 & 1486 & 1510 & 1579 & 1496 & 1623 & 1538 & 1491 & 1571 & 1489 & 1761 & 1885 & 1784 & 1696 & 1705 & 1717 & 1619 & 1597 \\
88 & 961 & 1127 & 1083 & 1133 & 1205 & 1124 & 1240 & 1259 & 1347 & 1405 & 1409 & 1388 & 1426 & 1439 & 1424 & 1454 & 1449 & 1460 & 1411 & 1671 & 1761 & 1688 & 1559 & 1677 & 1544 & 1481 \\
89 & 849 & 955 & 954 & 907 & 1049 & 972 & 1038 & 1114 & 1138 & 1158 & 1279 & 1203 & 1249 & 1344 & 1314 & 1255 & 1274 & 1338 & 1288 & 1377 & 1529 & 1586 & 1544 & 1556 & 1619 & 1535 \\
90 & 683 & 741 & 815 & 879 & 864 & 759 & 888 & 904 & 985 & 1039 & 1054 & 1058 & 1129 & 1135 & 1097 & 1102 & 1182 & 1136 & 1201 & 1176 & 1201 & 1456 & 1459 & 1537 & 1329 & 1418 \\
91 & 622 & 593 & 657 & 657 & 721 & 720 & 730 & 836 & 805 & 860 & 890 & 881 & 982 & 956 & 982 & 952 & 956 & 987 & 994 & 999 & 1052 & 1084 & 1305 & 1345 & 1351 & 1194 \\
92 & 473 & 473 & 509 & 531 & 557 & 560 & 606 & 623 & 636 & 690 & 729 & 767 & 778 & 812 & 759 & 830 & 847 & 884 & 878 & 871 & 892 & 894 & 955 & 1121 & 1169 & 1086 \\
93 & 350 & 357 & 406 & 387 & 461 & 430 & 474 & 493 & 505 & 529 & 547 & 573 & 615 & 700 & 635 & 670 & 735 & 684 & 740 & 736 & 735 & 747 & 758 & 800 & 981 & 946 \\
94 & 270 & 285 & 313 & 299 & 326 & 307 & 349 & 353 & 380 & 368 & 424 & 437 & 434 & 454 & 478 & 452 & 558 & 524 & 604 & 585 & 600 & 577 & 618 & 619 & 666 & 727 \\
95 & 184 & 199 & 234 & 253 & 235 & 234 & 268 & 257 & 275 & 284 & 291 & 330 & 336 & 363 & 360 & 377 & 404 & 358 & 419 & 431 & 464 & 414 & 449 & 519 & 480 & 512 \\
96 & 126 & 147 & 169 & 153 & 199 & 173 & 159 & 198 & 198 & 197 & 224 & 241 & 245 & 262 & 269 & 236 & 262 & 310 & 308 & 297 & 316 & 334 & 317 & 348 & 356 & 351 \\
97 & 107 & 120 & 104 & 118 & 125 & 136 & 124 & 132 & 156 & 127 & 144 & 140 & 159 & 166 & 166 & 176 & 206 & 191 & 202 & 221 & 221 & 243 & 252 & 254 & 250 & 268 \\
98 & 68 & 76 & 64 & 72 & 68 & 78 & 73 & 77 & 72 & 88 & 89 & 110 & 111 & 96 & 106 & 126 & 113 & 135 & 153 & 137 & 169 & 151 & 162 & 168 & 171 & 164 \\
99 & 46 & 33 & 51 & 50 & 58 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 60 & 57 & 60 & 63 & 71 & 76 & 59 & 62 & 55 & 81 & 82 & 95 & 104 & 108 & 102 & 132 & 116 & 105 \\
100$+$ & 63 & 56 & 72 & 63 & 69 & 64 & 72 & 88 & 78 & 74 & 83 & 80 & 100 & 95 & 94 & 97 & 93 & 108 & 128 & 130 & 146 & 165 & 128 & 166 & 156 & 190 
\end{tabular*}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make it a complete document, i.e., add all the relevant lines starting with `\documentclass`, up to `\end{document}`. Make sure that it compiles and shows the problem that you want to have solved.

Comment: the code is now updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the following things.

- `\hvFloat` needs two more arguments, the caption and the label; otherwise your MWE does not compile.
- Moreover, you have to load the `booktabs` package, since you use `\midrule`.
- The main change: The width available for the table is not `\textwidth`, but `\textheight` minus the space needed for the section heading (approx. `25pt` as determined from the overfull hbox warning). You can compute it as `\dimexpr\textheight-25pt`.
- The table has too many rows to set the font size to `\small`. Use `\scriptsize` instead, or split the table into two.
- I suggest to set `\tabcolsep` to `0pt` and distribute the available extra space by `\extracolsep{\fill}` between all columns.
- You have to terminate the `\setlength` command by a percent sign, otherwise you have a space to the left of the table that takes away some points.
- Finally you can gain some extra space by starting and finishing the column specifiers by `@{}`, which takes away the space to the left of the left column and to the right of the right column.

In the code below I also load the `showframe` package to mark the text area.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, leqno, oneside] {report}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{hvfloat}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\newpage
\section*{A.1 Death rate Male}
\hvFloat[nonFloat=true,capWidth=w,capPos=t,rotAngle=90]{table}{%
\scriptsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}%
\begin{tabular*}{\dimexpr\textheight-25pt}{@{}l*{26}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}@{}}
\AA r & 1989 & 1990 & 1991 & 1992 & 1993 & 1994 & 1995 & 1996 & 1997 & 1998 & 1999 & 2000 & 2001 & 2002 & 2003 & 2004 & 2005 & 2006 & 2007 & 2008 & 2009 & 2010 & 2011 & 2012 & 2013 & 2014 \\
\midrule
64 & 711 & 765 & 719 & 698 & 608 & 619 & 595 & 609 & 522 & 582 & 531 & 560 & 539 & 531 & 533 & 579 & 514 & 576 & 665 & 707 & 670 & 731 & 637 & 606 & 590 & 518 \\
65 & 843 & 804 & 774 & 778 & 721 & 698 & 620 & 653 & 673 & 626 & 557 & 553 & 551 & 544 & 620 & 600 & 617 & 644 & 669 & 686 & 734 & 739 & 743 & 669 & 652 & 616 \\
66 & 899 & 894 & 872 & 861 & 788 & 727 & 782 & 709 & 696 & 669 & 591 & 596 & 612 & 632 & 637 & 611 & 699 & 678 & 596 & 657 & 709 & 765 & 796 & 805 & 749 & 696 \\
67 & 1032 & 927 & 989 & 891 & 898 & 774 & 783 & 822 & 726 & 757 & 707 & 633 & 627 & 626 & 628 & 652 & 636 & 629 & 690 & 627 & 660 & 767 & 797 & 793 & 807 & 824 \\
68 & 1141 & 1119 & 1023 & 1026 & 980 & 909 & 896 & 846 & 809 & 775 & 801 & 724 & 724 & 687 & 710 & 682 & 703 & 663 & 697 & 741 & 651 & 697 & 844 & 803 & 878 & 866 \\
69 & 1324 & 1182 & 1197 & 1057 & 1048 & 986 & 968 & 921 & 868 & 861 & 829 & 827 & 766 & 790 & 705 & 739 & 721 & 708 & 715 & 780 & 763 & 755 & 830 & 856 & 914 & 954 \\
70 & 1122 & 1383 & 1311 & 1289 & 1144 & 1114 & 1043 & 1000 & 958 & 923 & 902 & 893 & 825 & 823 & 810 & 744 & 762 & 786 & 758 & 766 & 749 & 829 & 781 & 866 & 911 & 976 \\
71 & 1254 & 1271 & 1398 & 1349 & 1299 & 1155 & 1155 & 1170 & 1128 & 1040 & 1056 & 932 & 928 & 879 & 960 & 884 & 775 & 814 & 773 & 798 & 808 & 838 & 835 & 761 & 927 & 983 \\
72 & 1369 & 1368 & 1274 & 1495 & 1506 & 1347 & 1183 & 1158 & 1175 & 1139 & 1104 & 1086 & 988 & 1014 & 941 & 935 & 866 & 838 & 828 & 854 & 826 & 863 & 864 & 891 & 843 & 924 \\
73 & 1434 & 1423 & 1439 & 1386 & 1563 & 1500 & 1445 & 1318 & 1277 & 1232 & 1177 & 1116 & 1043 & 1080 & 1058 & 994 & 1010 & 906 & 884 & 861 & 913 & 877 & 923 & 993 & 943 & 869 \\
74 & 1583 & 1544 & 1505 & 1485 & 1397 & 1577 & 1723 & 1467 & 1399 & 1348 & 1287 & 1235 & 1182 & 1138 & 1121 & 1033 & 1088 & 1023 & 904 & 994 & 956 & 944 & 937 & 1032 & 1033 & 1064 \\
75 & 1622 & 1706 & 1621 & 1459 & 1534 & 1453 & 1660 & 1690 & 1587 & 1439 & 1475 & 1340 & 1272 & 1265 & 1197 & 1087 & 1137 & 1081 & 1062 & 1020 & 987 & 1033 & 985 & 1026 & 1071 & 1085 \\
76 & 1714 & 1752 & 1681 & 1569 & 1597 & 1548 & 1481 & 1694 & 1773 & 1705 & 1448 & 1453 & 1415 & 1302 & 1303 & 1224 & 1218 & 1189 & 1112 & 1051 & 1095 & 1014 & 1101 & 1086 & 1119 & 1116 \\
77 & 1862 & 1858 & 1874 & 1782 & 1795 & 1677 & 1678 & 1596 & 1776 & 1796 & 1700 & 1582 & 1510 & 1527 & 1445 & 1319 & 1284 & 1258 & 1219 & 1205 & 1171 & 1174 & 1129 & 1146 & 1126 & 1182 \\
78 & 1801 & 1888 & 1860 & 1822 & 1867 & 1714 & 1709 & 1593 & 1570 & 1870 & 1871 & 1687 & 1576 & 1600 & 1497 & 1373 & 1370 & 1334 & 1365 & 1307 & 1279 & 1325 & 1227 & 1196 & 1110 & 1197 \\
79 & 1874 & 1975 & 1854 & 1914 & 1856 & 1680 & 1796 & 1706 & 1665 & 1595 & 1919 & 1906 & 1788 & 1681 & 1621 & 1504 & 1566 & 1435 & 1345 & 1335 & 1295 & 1349 & 1319 & 1246 & 1219 & 1196 \\
80 & 1786 & 1906 & 1862 & 1882 & 1994 & 1860 & 1755 & 1763 & 1791 & 1652 & 1653 & 1879 & 1934 & 1846 & 1698 & 1630 & 1643 & 1580 & 1529 & 1468 & 1495 & 1452 & 1366 & 1400 & 1320 & 1288 \\
81 & 1819 & 1983 & 1968 & 1872 & 1933 & 1837 & 1821 & 1860 & 1815 & 1775 & 1816 & 1624 & 1975 & 1944 & 1990 & 1745 & 1741 & 1698 & 1603 & 1647 & 1503 & 1484 & 1365 & 1538 & 1405 & 1350 \\
82 & 1686 & 1810 & 1898 & 1940 & 1890 & 1775 & 1919 & 1821 & 1706 & 1761 & 1803 & 1763 & 1586 & 2045 & 1987 & 1777 & 1777 & 1698 & 1700 & 1639 & 1540 & 1560 & 1512 & 1544 & 1485 & 1486 \\
83 & 1671 & 1699 & 1792 & 1841 & 1845 & 1753 & 1814 & 1873 & 1795 & 1789 & 1793 & 1757 & 1753 & 1658 & 2068 & 1922 & 1900 & 1766 & 1758 & 1724 & 1653 & 1660 & 1662 & 1587 & 1515 & 1566 \\
84 & 1560 & 1632 & 1671 & 1681 & 1791 & 1728 & 1834 & 1804 & 1783 & 1845 & 1709 & 1729 & 1697 & 1715 & 1606 & 1959 & 2003 & 1917 & 1809 & 1761 & 1707 & 1648 & 1665 & 1661 & 1659 & 1540 \\
85 & 1395 & 1449 & 1543 & 1601 & 1659 & 1594 & 1718 & 1745 & 1713 & 1794 & 1719 & 1703 & 1697 & 1719 & 1710 & 1606 & 1963 & 1942 & 1816 & 1775 & 1808 & 1715 & 1712 & 1672 & 1598 & 1647 \\
86 & 1280 & 1424 & 1333 & 1404 & 1556 & 1460 & 1665 & 1635 & 1588 & 1641 & 1709 & 1695 & 1578 & 1605 & 1656 & 1574 & 1586 & 1902 & 1919 & 1828 & 1714 & 1748 & 1697 & 1741 & 1601 & 1605 \\
87 & 1141 & 1171 & 1210 & 1266 & 1368 & 1260 & 1375 & 1494 & 1440 & 1486 & 1510 & 1579 & 1496 & 1623 & 1538 & 1491 & 1571 & 1489 & 1761 & 1885 & 1784 & 1696 & 1705 & 1717 & 1619 & 1597 \\
88 & 961 & 1127 & 1083 & 1133 & 1205 & 1124 & 1240 & 1259 & 1347 & 1405 & 1409 & 1388 & 1426 & 1439 & 1424 & 1454 & 1449 & 1460 & 1411 & 1671 & 1761 & 1688 & 1559 & 1677 & 1544 & 1481 \\
89 & 849 & 955 & 954 & 907 & 1049 & 972 & 1038 & 1114 & 1138 & 1158 & 1279 & 1203 & 1249 & 1344 & 1314 & 1255 & 1274 & 1338 & 1288 & 1377 & 1529 & 1586 & 1544 & 1556 & 1619 & 1535 \\
90 & 683 & 741 & 815 & 879 & 864 & 759 & 888 & 904 & 985 & 1039 & 1054 & 1058 & 1129 & 1135 & 1097 & 1102 & 1182 & 1136 & 1201 & 1176 & 1201 & 1456 & 1459 & 1537 & 1329 & 1418 \\
91 & 622 & 593 & 657 & 657 & 721 & 720 & 730 & 836 & 805 & 860 & 890 & 881 & 982 & 956 & 982 & 952 & 956 & 987 & 994 & 999 & 1052 & 1084 & 1305 & 1345 & 1351 & 1194 \\
92 & 473 & 473 & 509 & 531 & 557 & 560 & 606 & 623 & 636 & 690 & 729 & 767 & 778 & 812 & 759 & 830 & 847 & 884 & 878 & 871 & 892 & 894 & 955 & 1121 & 1169 & 1086 \\
93 & 350 & 357 & 406 & 387 & 461 & 430 & 474 & 493 & 505 & 529 & 547 & 573 & 615 & 700 & 635 & 670 & 735 & 684 & 740 & 736 & 735 & 747 & 758 & 800 & 981 & 946 \\
94 & 270 & 285 & 313 & 299 & 326 & 307 & 349 & 353 & 380 & 368 & 424 & 437 & 434 & 454 & 478 & 452 & 558 & 524 & 604 & 585 & 600 & 577 & 618 & 619 & 666 & 727 \\
95 & 184 & 199 & 234 & 253 & 235 & 234 & 268 & 257 & 275 & 284 & 291 & 330 & 336 & 363 & 360 & 377 & 404 & 358 & 419 & 431 & 464 & 414 & 449 & 519 & 480 & 512 \\
96 & 126 & 147 & 169 & 153 & 199 & 173 & 159 & 198 & 198 & 197 & 224 & 241 & 245 & 262 & 269 & 236 & 262 & 310 & 308 & 297 & 316 & 334 & 317 & 348 & 356 & 351 \\
97 & 107 & 120 & 104 & 118 & 125 & 136 & 124 & 132 & 156 & 127 & 144 & 140 & 159 & 166 & 166 & 176 & 206 & 191 & 202 & 221 & 221 & 243 & 252 & 254 & 250 & 268 \\
98 & 68 & 76 & 64 & 72 & 68 & 78 & 73 & 77 & 72 & 88 & 89 & 110 & 111 & 96 & 106 & 126 & 113 & 135 & 153 & 137 & 169 & 151 & 162 & 168 & 171 & 164 \\
99 & 46 & 33 & 51 & 50 & 58 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 60 & 57 & 60 & 63 & 71 & 76 & 59 & 62 & 55 & 81 & 82 & 95 & 104 & 108 & 102 & 132 & 116 & 105 \\
100$+$ & 63 & 56 & 72 & 63 & 69 & 64 & 72 & 88 & 78 & 74 & 83 & 80 & 100 & 95 & 94 & 97 & 93 & 108 & 128 & 130 & 146 & 165 & 128 & 166 & 156 & 190 
\end{tabular*}}{Long caption}{float label}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works perfect! Thanks, I never thought of editing in the table settings.

Answer (score 0):

use the option  `floatPos=p` . 
If you do not want to load the lscape package you can use the `floatPos=p`
option to put the image on an own page and rotated by 90 degrees.

Comment: it didn't work.